# Set Property Not Working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm working on an ASP.NET MVC 5 (5.2.2) app in which I got a model:

```
public class MyModel{
    private String _Password;
    [Required]
    [StringLength(int.MaxValue, MinimumLength=6)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string Password {
        get
        {
            return Shell.ToolBox.Cryptography.GetMD5(_Password);
        }
        set {
            _Password = value; // This is not called
        }
    }
 }
```

The value of the `_Password` is always null, and when I change this property to an automatic type problem is solved. What is wrong, I used a break point, the set method is not even reached.

View:

```
<br />
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Password, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Password, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
```

Comment: Where is the code that would normally call the setter?

Comment: Idea: does `Shell.ToolBox.Cryptography.GetMD5` handle a null input? Try checking for null and passing blank instead.

Comment: So, I created a new MVC 5 project and tried it out, and I'm not seeing the problem. I don't know where to look for that Shell.ToolBox namespace. I tried it without the MD5 hash and using System.Security.Cryptography's MD5 method.

Comment: @Blorgbeard: No it does not, because null cannot be converted to byte[]

Comment: @AustinMullins: This is really strange, I still can't figure it out, I think maybe and maybe the `unobtrusive jquery validation` may have caused it

Comment: @Tom well `_Password` is null before it is first set. If anything was to read the value of `Password` before it was first set, that would cause an exception, yes?

Comment: @Blorgbeard: The problem is not like that, the SET is not reached after the data is posted! and the _Password is ALWAYS null no matter what happens because it is never set. I've checked that by breakpoint, I can get to the GET method but the SET method is never called. That is the strange part.

Comment: I'm saying that the GET will throw an exception, which might be causing the set not to be called. Try initializing `_Password = string.Empty` and see what happens.

Comment: @Blorgbeard: That will result in passing empty string, I exactly understand what you mean Blorgbeard, but the problem is that when my model is posted from the view, the SET method in this model is not called at all. That seems weird. I've been trying to figure that out for a couple of days :D.

Comment: Just humour me and try it?

Comment: @Blorgbeard: even if I change the Get to `return _Password;`, I still get the null value, do you understand what I'm trying to say

Comment: @Blorgbeard: I mean that the model is fine, problem is somewhere else probably something is messing up with posting the data

Comment: Wait, so an auto-property worked fine.. but a simple `get { return _Password; }` does not? What if you change the set to `set { _Password = value; }`?

Comment: @Blorgbeard: the set is already `set {_Password = value;}` but automatic types are ok. Is there anyway a JQuery library could cause anything like this?

Comment: I have no idea what's going on, because auto-properties are just syntactic sugar, and the compiled code will be almost identical to `get { return _Password; } set { _Password = value; }`. I cannot imagine a JQuery library being able to tell in any way whether the property is auto or not.

Comment: @Blorgbeard: I gave up to this, I just changed it to the automatic type and converted the string to the MD5 somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

[@Blorgbeard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/369/blorgbeard) revealed the solution. See the following model:

```cs
public class Dummy
{
    private string _field;

    [Required]
    [StringLength(int.MaxValue, MinimumLength=6)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string Field
    {
        get
        {
            if (_field == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("Argh!");
            }

            return Utils.ByteArrayConverter.ByteArrayToString(
                MD5CryptoServiceProvider.Create(_field).Hash); 
        }
        set
        {
            _field = value;
        }
    }
}
```

I added the check for `null` (which throws an exception) to simulate what would happen if the MD5 hash function couldn't handle a null value argument. Sure enough, the page acts as if `Field` is always null, and the debug window logs the `ArgumentNullException`. In your case, we can still use the `Shell.Toolbox` version, but we just need to check for null first:

```cs
var pwd = _Password;
if (pwd == null)
{
    pwd = string.Empty;
}

return Shell.ToolBox.Cryptography.GetMD5(pwd);
```

Comment: The problem is not like that, the SET is not reached after the data is posted! and the _Password is ALWAYS null no matter what happens because it is never set. Handling the null will not solve any part of it because, It keeps throwing that exception then.

Comment: I'll admit I'm no ASP expert, but I did replicate your problem on a fresh project, and it appeared to go away when I replaced the code that threw an exception. Maybe another user will offer a better explanation / solution.